# My Android app is not getting any response from server

Tags: php, android, json

I'm a beginner in Android. Actually I'm trying to receive data from server and check that the entered username and password is correct or not, but it's not getting any response event showing "Wrong Match". I also checked the JSON output it is suppose to show success if entered "Hello" as name and "Hi" as password but it's not showing anything on button click. I've also added Internet permission in **`Manifest.xml`**.

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.43.218/define_testing.php";
 EditText username,pass;
 Button login;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    login.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 StringRequest request=new StringRequest(REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsO= new JSONObject(response);

                                JSONArray array = null;

                                array = jsO.getJSONArray("result");

                                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
                                    String name= obj.getString("name");
                                    String password=obj.getString("password");

                                    String enterName=username.getText().toString();
                                    String enterPass=pass.getText().toString();
                                    if(name.equals(enterName) && password.equals(enterPass)){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }



                            }
                            catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }},new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Internet Problem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                    requestQueue.add(request);
                }
            }
    );


   }

 }
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php
 require ('connection.php');

  $name  = 'Hello';

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM new_one_user_information WHERE username='".$name."'";

 $r = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

 $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$result = array();

array_push($result,array(
"name"=>$res['username'],
"password"=>$res['password']
      )
     );

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));


 mysqli_close($connect);
 ?>
```

Output of this PHP script is:

```
Connection Established
{"result":[{"name":"Hello","password":"Hi"}]}
```

Error in logcat:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
  at com.example.srinu.stackview2.MainActivity.checkIt(MainActivity.java:85)
  at com.example.srinu.stackview2.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:68)
  at com.example.srinu.stackview2.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:50)
  at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
  at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: give the error messages and crash report if any?

Comment: @Xenolion No sir there's no error message

Comment: @SrinivasNahak Try this tutorial for use : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-login-example-using-php-mysql-and-volley/

Comment: @NitinPatel sure Sir I'll follow that tutorial but can you point out the mistake in my program

Comment: @SrinivasNahak Check your url is working even in mobile browser (if you can check it). And Debug the code and check what you can get in response. Hope this will guide you more.

Comment: @NitinPatel Sir I've checked url is fine but it's not showing success or wrong match toast either

Comment: @SrinivasNahak Better Put debug point "JSONObject jsO= new JSONObject" on this line and check value of response. Debug the code if you don't know learn it and check it.

Comment: Hey brother, first thing because you want a JsonObject the volley library supports also JsonObjectRequest not only StringRequest. Although this is not the cause of your error. I guess `username` and `pass` should be final in order to be used in inner classes! @SrinivasNahak

Comment: I think that maybe you are echoing "Connection Established" inside the required connection.php file. And that's the reason why it is not a valid json. Could you check it?

Comment: @jeprubio Thank you so much sir u just saved my life

Comment: I'm glad to help. I write this as an answer in case anybody else has a similar problem and finds this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a "Connection Established" message inside the required connection.php file.

And that's the reason why the php response is not a valid json.

Comment: Did it work? If so, you can mark this answer as correct so that this question will not appear as unanswered anymore.